# How to join tables and include entries where not in both tables?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables like:

Table A

```
+-----------+---------------+
| AccountID | NumberOfAdams |
+-----------+---------------+
| A1        |             2 |
| A2        |             5 |
| A3        |             10|
+-----------+---------------+
```

Table B:

```
+-----------+----------------+
| AccountID | NumberOfBrowns |
+-----------+----------------+
| A3        |             13 |
+-----------+----------------+
```

Using a `LEFT JOIN`, with table B as the first table, the resulting table is:

```
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| AccountID | NumberOfAdams | NumberOfBrowns |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| A3        |            10 |             13 |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
```

What I want to get is:

```
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| AccountID | NumberOfAdams | NumberOfBrowns |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
| A1        |             2 | NULL           |
| A2        |             5 | NULL           |
| A3        |            10 | 13             |
+-----------+---------------+----------------+
```

**How can I retrieve all AccountIDs from both with a `JOIN`?**

Comment: Why not `A left join B`

Comment: @ProGu Because if AccountIDs are in B and not A then they wont be included

Comment: to make it clear, if there is A4 in table B, you want to show it in the result set as well?

Comment: @ProGu yep, thats correct

Comment: a `LEFT JOIN` should work, unless you are filtering table b in the `WHERE` clause instead of  the `ON` clause. Show us the query.

Answer (score 1):

This query might work

```
SELECT p.AccountID, a.NumberOfAdams, b.NumberOfBrowns
FROM (
 SELECT AccountID
 FROM table_a
 UNION 
 SELECT AccountID
 FROM table_b
) p
LEFT JOIN table_a a ON p.AccountID = a.AccountID
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON p.AccountID = b.AccountID
```